# Как занести введённую с клавиатуры строку в массив?

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки, циклы, prompt

Есть переменная в цикле arrAnswear, нужно занести в неё ответы введённые пользователем через prompt. Чтобы после каждого цикла, значение заносилось в массив и их можно было использовать в дальнейшем. Как реализовать это? На Java ответ нашёл, на js не получается

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var alright = 0;
            var sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4 = 0;
            // массивы массивные 
            var arrAnswear = ["Загадка № 1: Не вода, не суша — на лодке не уплывёшь и ногами не пройдёшь?",
                                "Загадка № 2: В воде не тонет в огне не горит?",
                                "Загадка № 3: Живёт без тела, говорит без языка, никто его не видит, а всякий слышит?",
                                "Загадка № 4: И в тайге, и в океане он отыщет путь любой. умещается в кармане, а ведёт нас за собой?"];
            var arrCorrect = ["болото",
                                "лед",
                                "эхо",
                                "компас"];          

            //Загадки
            var j = 0;
            while (j < 4) 
            {
                var sum;
                var sum_all = sum + j;

                var userAnswear = prompt(arrAnswear[j]);    
                if (userAnswear.toLowerCase() == arrCorrect[j])
                {
                    alert("Вы ответили верно");
                    sum_all++;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Вы ответили неверно");
                }
                j++;


            }
            alert("Игра окончена");

            //на какие вопросы ответили верно
            var i = 0;

            while (i < 4) // цикл, попытка упрощения
            {
                var sum_all = sum + i;


                if (sum_all == 1)
                {
                    document.write('<p>' + arrAnswear[i] + '<br> Вы ответили: <b>&quot;' + userAnswear + '&quot;</b> и это верный ответ.</p>');
                }
                else
                {
                    document.write('<p>' + arrAnswear[i] + '<br> Вы ответили: <b>&quot;' + userAnswear + '&quot;</b> и вы не угадали. Верный ответ: <b>&quot;' + arrCorrect[i] + '&quot;</b></p>');
                }
                i++;
            }


            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  arr[i] = prompt('enter something', '');
}
alert(arr);
```

Comment: Эх, ну push же...

Comment: не получается и через push